# file permission is not correct while copying files with SCP

Tags: unix, ssh, scp

we are trying to copy files from one server to another but the permissions of copied files are not correct.
I have tried following solution but its not working.

http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2007/11/setting-basic-file-permissions-in-non.html

currently  permission is set to  :   -rw-------
We want to change the permissions to -rw-rw-r—

Any one faced this issue ?

EDIT:
We have Unix on both the sides.

Answer (score 3):

Use the "-p" flag to preserve permissions when copying with SCP.

Source: http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/scp.html

Comment: Sorry, no, the -p option preserves creation times and modes, not file permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I've set this with a chmod after the copy.

```
scp /path/to/file server:/path/to/file
ssh server chmod 664 /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your `umask` on the remote side.  I'll bet it looks like `077`.

Answer (score 1):

If you run WinSCP, there's an option set perms after the upload.  Other than that, I believe that the only thing you can do is to chmod after the upload.

Comment: @NinjaCat: actually same thing is working in many other production env. I don't know why in that env its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something more advanced like `rsync`, perhaps it has the needed options.

Comment: thanks for response but i cant :(. we have same thing working in many env  and I cant change it.